# Find the day of every nth week of a month (e.g. find Friday of second week of next month knowing Friday the second week of this month)

Tags: php, calendar

How to find day of week of nth week of a month.

Example: today (10th) is a 3rd week of August, on 14th it will be a third week of September and also Sunday. How would I find 14th of September knowing the 10th of August?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtotime()`.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

And relative date format.
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first Sunday of September')); //2014-09-07
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('second Sunday of September')); //2014-09-14
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('third Sunday of September')); //2014-09-21
```